# How do I format a DateTime string in javascript from using slashes to using hypens?

Tags: javascript

I have an input date string in the following format:

```
yyyy/mm/dd
```

This is my desired output date string format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

Is there a built-in way to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
date = date.replace(/\//g, '-');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Av3xn/)

If for some reason you don't want to use a regex

```
date = date.split('/').join('-');
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using formatting, rather than regexes?  Seems more maintainable.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - More maintainable how? What can be more maintainable than a simple string.replace ?

Comment: There is a downside to the .join implementation: performance. I don't have the link handy but someone here did a performance comparison and the Javascript regex function evaluated substantially faster.

Comment: It's easier from a readability perspective to parse in a DateTime, then output it with a format, like yyyy-mm-dd as shown in the ticket.  But maybe that's not available in Javascript.  I was just asking :)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - In javascript there's the `Date.Parse`, but it's unreliable, so you have to pass in a valid date to `new Date()`, then get all the parts, and concantenate them together, not a very good solution for a simple string replacement issue.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I didn't do it for readability or of performance but I did us `new Date()` in my answer to show how we can go from the string "yyyy/mm/dd" to and date format. Regex works for this case so this is a great answer but my answer is for those that want to do something like "mm-dd-yyyy" or any date format that you want to build out.

Answer (score 3):

Adeneo's answer did solve this particular case but I would like to show how you can get this to any format you want. We start by getting the date that is shown as a date object by the calls `new Date()` ad passing it the date string:

```
var dateStr = "1991/01/11";
var d = new Date(dateStr);
```

Now we can call any of the getters listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Getter) to get that value and build out the desired string:

```
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
curr_month++;  //We add +1 because Jan is indexed at 0 instead of 1
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
console.log(curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date);
```

This allows us to build any format we want.