# Javascript Local Time Conversion + format change

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

What is the easiest method to simply convert the javascript date function to the local time ( in this case i'm just going to keep it constant and put Eastern Standard time)?? I am able to change the format to the actual months and remove the "/" but I need to include the actual time in this is well.

Thank you .

Comment: have a look at this: [convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: I need to change the format so it doesn't have multiple "/" because i'm storing this in a database and it doesn't like the slashes.

Comment: most of those methods still have the "/" in them. I am able to convert now, but am having trouble changing what I have to a different format.

Comment: I think this question should point you in the right direction. You are going to need something that's just a tad custom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291392/how-do-i-format-a-datetime-string-in-javascript-from-using-slashes-to-using-hype

Comment: @TarasTataryn just replace the / with something else like Luke Becker pointed with the link in his comment

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out through these links even though I had been on them earlier!